# US Domestic Airline Baggage Allowance?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, united-airlines, american-airlines

I have been checking to see what the Domestic Flight baggage allowance is for flights in the US.

I will be using mainly United Airlines and American Airlines.

Some sites are saying 23kg others are saying 18kg.

To make matters even worse the [UA website](https://www.united.com/CMS/en-US/travel/Pages/BaggageChecked.aspx) is broken and does not detail any information I require.

Was hoping someone with experience can confirm what the allowance is and what is the fee for checked in baggage?

Comment: The URL you give works fine for me; it says each bag may weigh up to 50 pounds (23 kg).  That page has a link to the list of fees; it is $25 for the first bag and $35 for the second.

Comment: @NateEldredge ; hmm it doesnt work for me all I get is an empty page. I was using Firefox, what were you using?

Comment: FIrefox 11.0 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually domestic flights don't have allowance at all on most of the airlines, at least those mentioned.

You have to pay additional charge to check in your bags. Up to 18kg per bag would definitely be fine, you would probably be OK with 21kg regardless of what the sites say as well. United state on the site you quoted 50lb, which is almost 23kg.

You're a paying customer, you're not getting this service for free (unless its an international connection, then its your international allowance anyway).

Comment: why was it downvoted?..

Comment: I didnt downvote you :(

Comment: Note that this is not always true if you have frequent flyer status. For example, on American, even with 'just' AAdvantage Gold, your bag fees are waived domestically: http://www.aa.com/i18n/AAdvantage/eliteStatus/elite-benefits-chart.jsp

Answer (score 4):

Typically, airlines in the USA use a piece-based baggage allowance policy. Each piece can usually be up to 50 pounds (23 kg). However, this policy may vary by ailrine, and in many cases, a fee is required for checking bags. On some of the ultra-low-cost airlines, you may even be charged for your carry-on baggage/hand luggage.

Kayak, FareCompare, and Airfare Watchdog maintain baggage fee and/or allowance tables. These sites link to airline websites for more details.

- [Kayak Fee Chart](http://www.kayak.com/airline-fees) (domestic USA)
- [FareCompare Worldwide Baggage Fee Chart](http://www.farecompare.com/about/worldwide-baggage-fee-chart/) (domestic USA & international)
- [Airfare Watchdog Baggage Fee Chart](http://www.airfarewatchdog.com/blog/3801089/airline-baggage-fees-chart-updated/) (domestic USA)